# Player movement on Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and for my first game I decided to make an endless runner like Temple Run. I have got the basic terrain set up but I am having problems with making the player move correctly. My player is a 3d cube and as soon as the game starts it moves forward, I want it to when I press the left arrow key to take a left turn and keep moving in the direction of the turn and when I press the right arrow key to take a right turn and keep moving in the direction of the turn.

Currently, I am using `Vector3.left` and `Vector3.right` along with `transform.rotate`. This does not give the desired effect. For example, when I press the right arrow key, the object rotates and takes a right turn but when I press right again to make another right turn only the object rotates (because the object is already moving in Vector.right direction).

Hopefully, this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

This is the code i'm using and its not working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    private Vector3 dir;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        dir = Vector3.zero;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            dir = Vector3.forward;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            dir = Vector3.right;
            transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
            Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            dir = Vector3.left;
            transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
            Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90, Vector3.up);
        }

        float amountToMove = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(dir * amountToMove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector3.right is only short for a Vector pointing to (0, 0, 1), it has little to do with the orientation of your gameobject. there also are `transform.forward/right/up`, which consider the objects rotation. 
Basically, if you always want to move your object forward, use `transform.forward` for simplicity and rotate its transform with `transform.Rotate(..)` or `transform.RotateAround(..)` or something similar (or you could use quaternions, but if that doesnt tell you anything right away, stay away from them and use the functions)